# Inheritance: possible to change base reference to something else?

Tags: c#, .net

For example I have two classes, Base and Derived as shown below:

```
class Base  
{        
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Base()
    {

    }
}

class Derived : Base
{
    public Derived(Base b)
    {
        base = b; // doesn't compile, but is there any way to do something similar?
    }
}
```

So that they behave like this:

```
Base b = new Base();
b.Name = "Bob";
Derived d = new Derived(b);
d.Name = "John";
// b.Name is now "John" also
```

Is this possible?  I guess one way would be to keep the Base b reference in Derived and override Derived.Name to point to b.Name?  Is there an easier way though, for example if I have like 50 properties to override?

```
class Derived : Base
{
    Base b;

    public override string Name
    {
        get { return b.Name; }
        set { b.Name = value; }
    }

    public Derived(Base b)
    {
        this.b = b;
    }
}
```

EDIT:

I guess another way to say it would be that I am creating a sort of wrapper for class Base.  I am given an object of type Base and want to wrap it with class Derived but still keep Base's original public properties/methods/etc.  I'm not sure if that makes it more clear or not.

Comment: You can use reflection to copy all properties

Comment: Derived classes don't have separate Bases; Derived is a single class.  Your question doesn't really make sense.  What are you trying to actually accomplish by creating a Derived with a constructor that takes a Base?

Comment: Can you provide a little more detail about what the actual goal is? You can't replace a base class, but their may be a way to accomplish the goal if it was clearer what the aim is. It sounds like Derived isn't really a Base in your example. Perhaps the two classes should be implementing a common interface.

Comment: I receive an object of type Base, and I want to "evolve" it's functionality, keeping this original Base object around. So the question is how best to do this?  The Base class is not modifiable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think from what you seem to be hinting at ( atleast from the edit - "I am creating a sort of wrapper for class Base"), you are looking at using the Decorator pattern:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern

> The decorator pattern can be used to extend (decorate) the
>   functionality of a certain object at run-time, independently of other
>   instances of the same class, provided some groundwork is done at
>   design time. This is achieved by designing a new decorator class that
>   wraps the original class.

Comment: So close but you beat me to it.

Comment: Thanks that sounds like exactly what I'm looking for.  So to be clear, that last code block is probably going in the right direction then?

Comment: @fred - Look at the examples in the wikipedia link. Research on the decorator pattern and see if it fits what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Guess I'm confused

```
public BaseClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
}

DerivedClass d = new DerivedClass();
d.Name = "Test";
BaseClass b = d as BaseClass;
print b.Name;
```

Output:

```
Test
```

The derived object inherits the methods, properties, fields and constructors(to some extend) of the base class, why override them when you can just use them.

Comment: Maybe he receives a base class and he wants to "evolve" it.

Comment: Sounds like an XY Problem (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378)

Comment: Yeah, Dani is right -- I receive an object of type Base, and I want to "evolve" it's functionality, keeping this original Base object around.  So the question is how best to do this?  t

Answer (score 1):

Have you heard of the Decorator Pattern? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern
It's a way of dynamically modifying behavior at runtime by wrapping instances of classes within themselves like Russian Dolls. They all implement the same interface so to the user of the class the wrapped and unwrapped versions appear the same.

```
Interface IDecorator{
    public void foo();
}

public class OuterDecorator:IDecorator{
    private IDecorator _inner;
    public OuterDecorator(IDecorator inner){
        this.__inner = inner;
    }

    public void foo(){
        this._inner.foo();
        Console.Writeline("Hello from outer");
    }
}

public class InnerDecorator:IDecorator{
    public void foo(){
        Console.Writeline("Hello from inner");
    }
}
```

You can make a static function be a Factory Method.

```
public static IDecorator GetDecorator(){
    var inner = new InnerDecorator();
    var outer = new OuterDecorator(inner);
    return outer;
}
```

And use it like so. The advantage is that the consumer of this class doesn't need to know the implementation details of the concrete class doing the work. Since both InnerDecorator and OuterDecorator implement the same interface they can be used interchangeably.

```
IDecorator d = OuterDecorator.GetDecorator();
d.foo();
//Output
//Hello from Inner
//Hello from Outer
```

Answer (score 0):

here's some more information on the decorator pattern:

- [HeadFirst Design Patterns](http://oreilly.com/catalog/hfdesignpat/chapter/ch03.pdf) - start here
- [DoFactory](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternDecorator.aspx)